# How to use the `db` variable from other controllers in AccountController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to use Identity in my application. I don't know how to change the **User** table. So I decided to create an additional model **Avatar** for images.

```
public class Avatar
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; } 

        [Required]
        public int AvatarId { get; set; }
    }
```

In **Register** action of **AccountController** I want to add default avatar for all users:

```
// POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    Avatar defaultAvatar = new Avatar { UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId(), ImagePath = "default.png"};
                    db.Avatars.Add(defaultAvatar);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

But I have an error: The name 'db' does not exist in the current context. I chose the correct way to realization of my idea? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: `db` is an instance of your context class, you need to create one, for example `var db = new IdentityDbContext();`

Answer (score 2):

Certain controllers that you generate through a template get a `private YourDbContext db = new YourDbContext();` member. This lets you access the database in any action method.

If you want that in your `AccountController` as well, you need to add that declaration there too.

Or rather wrap it in a `using` block:

```
using (var db = new YourDbContext())
{
    db.Avatars.Add(defaultAvatar);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must instantiate the DbContext in your controllers constrctor.

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    public YourController()
    {
        _db = new ApplicationDbContext;
    }

    //Optional: Poor man's dependency injection for unit test
    //Also I highly recommend to have a look at IOC containers.
    public YourController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
}
```